# Why mockito crash when mocking the DAO?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, dao, android-room

I am currently writing a unit test. but mockito crashes when I tried to mock a DAO interface.
Below is the test code. It basically just trying to mock an interface.

```
class RepoTest {
    @Test
    fun testDelete() {
        val dao = Mockito.mock(ExchangeRateItemMainPageDAO::class.java)
    }
}
```

And the DAO interface code is as below:

```
@Dao
interface ExchangeRateItemMainPageDAO {
    @Insert
    fun insertExchangeRateItem(item: ExchangeRateItemMainPage)

    @Delete
    fun deleteExchangeRateItem(item:ExchangeRateItemMainPage)
}
```

Where as the message given when the test failed is below:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:12)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:11)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:44)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:975)
    at com.lazyfire.curencyexchg.currencypawn.viewModel.RepoTest.testDelete(MainActivityViewModelTest.kt:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: I see some NullPointerException in the stack trace (3rd line from the bottom). I'd use a debugger to check what reference is null. It may be a good clue to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you use static initializer blocks somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just something went wrong in cache. Just invalidate cache and restart and it works fine then.

Comment: this should be a comment in your question or edit to it